# how to make that node still moving while sending a Airframe messages in veins example?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm working on the veins example in Omnetpp.
In the veins Omnetpp example, I amrun the Erlangen simulation. While sending airframe messages, all nodes were stopped and then they continue moving after finishing sending messages to RSU.

How to make that node still moving while sending messages?
thenk you for helping

Answer (score 0):

The nodes do not actually stop moving. The simulation is slowed down a lot so the communication between vehicles and the RSU can be visualised. As all the communication happens in a split second the nodes only seem to be standing still. In reality they are moving very slowly.